# how to create complex grid in bootstrap and be responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i create below grid by this code ,
complex grid bootstrap:

[image]

but when resize the browser window,panels layout not true.excuse me if my eng language is not good.

[image]

```css
.mm{
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid black;
    color:black;
    font:bold 50px b yekan;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pad "><div class="mm" style="height:150px;background-color:#c78221">1</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pad"><div class="mm" style="height:300px;background-color:#ffd800">2</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pad" style="top:-150px"><div class="mm" style=" height:300px;background-color:#9158ee">3</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pad" style="top:-150px"><div class=" mm" style="height:150px;background-color:#ff006e">4</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3  pad" style="top:-300px"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3  pad" style="top:-300px"><div class="mm" style="height:150px;background-color:#4cff00">5</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-4  pad" style="top:-300px"><div class="mm" style="height:300px;background-color:#1f9cdc">6</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-4   pad" style="top:-300px"><div class="mm " style="height:300px;background-color:#ff00dc">7</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 pad" style="top:-450px"><div class="mm" style="height:150px;background-color:#1a8d43">8</div></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First see the official bootstrap page and learn how to grid system work.
[***Grid system here***](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

**i have created a demo for  you  on bootply**

[**Bootply demo**](http://www.bootply.com/render/jUwhbQ41E6)

hope this help